# Some of my applications broke after a software update

Tags: google-chrome, update-manager, c++, visual-studio-code

I really hate to be that kind of guy, but I have struggled with this for a couple of days and its stressing me really out. I would say that I am fairly knowledgeable about technical things and not completely incompetent.

After a software update with the Software-Update application some weird behavior in my system started appearing. I cannot open Google Chrome anymore, yes I have reinstalled it, and in VS Code I get squiggly lines for basic includes like  that I did not have before and it is apparently not that easily fixable, since I have tried a couple of things already. Furthermore there is some weird behavior and errors here and there.
I cannot conclusively say that this happend to to the update but I am pretty confident it has something to do with it.
I know that my description of things is horrible, I tried googling the things that broke but I am not able to find anything even remotely related or that helps.

Now here is the true question: What is the standard procedure if something is messed up in Ubuntu and you have no idea why. What dials do you turn and what knobs do you push to get to the root of this.

Thanks

Comment: It may be helpful to note what exact version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Your system keeps many kinds kinds of records to aid troubleshooting: Crash dumps in `/var/crash`, syslogs in `/var/log/` and the `journalctl` command, and of course the apt history log in `/var/log/apt/`

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: The "standard procedure" is: read `man`, `info`, `help`, `README` files (install the `-dev` package). Make a mental model of what the system is trying to do, and how it's doing it. Compare the model with the observed misbehavior. Learning is involved.